# PXE boot pmagic with wget or TFTP after kernel

Tags: pxe-boot, wget, tftp

I wish to boot parted magic by PXE.

I have read this article on the topic: https://partedmagic.com/pxe/
where it states that you can either load the entire iso, prepare the squashfs file and load it as ramdisk or you can load a kernel and then afterwards have busybox download the file in a variety of ways, including http/s and TFTP. It also states that this method might be faster than using the TFTP client of the network boot loader from BIOS/UEFI.

I have tried the memdisk kernel loading the iso way and it works fine. I have also had success with the "Download all files in boot-loader using TFTP" way, loading the packaged files created by the script.

```
label                   pmagic_fast
        menu label      Parted Magic Fast
        linux           pmagic/bzImage
        initrd          pmagic/initrd.img,pmagic/fu.img,pmagic/m.img,pmagic/files.cgz
        append          edd=on vga=normal

label                   pmagic_full
        menu label      Parted Magic Full
        linux           pmagic/memdisk
        initrd          pmagic/pmagic_2021_08_30.iso
        append          iso
```

Since I'm using TFTP anyway, I wanted to use the method that downloads things after loading the linux kernel. I am using a custom menu with `vesamenu.c32`. The menu works fine. The relevant entry is

```
label                   pmagic_fast_tftp
        menu label      Parted Magic Fast Test TFTP
        linux           pmagic/bzImage
        initrd          pmagic/initrd.img,pmagic/fu.img,pmagic/m.img
        append          edd=on vga=normal netsrc=tftp neturl="192.168.1.5:/pmagic/pmodules"
```

It states in the article that you have to supply `netsrc` and `neturl` as kernel arguments. I put them where I think they belong, but I'm not sure. They didn't provide a full example.

`PMAGIC_2021_08_30.SQFS` is inside `/srv/tftp/pmagic/pmodules/`, TFTP is served from `/srv/tftp/` using dnsmasq, since I'm using dnsmasq anyway because of pihole.

Since this didn't work, I also tried the wget method mentioned in the article.

```
label                   pmagic_fast_wget1
        menu label      Parted Magic Fast Test WGET1
        linux           pmagic/bzImage
        initrd          pmagic/initrd.img,pmagic/fu.img,pmagic/m.img
        append          edd=on vga=normal netsrc=wget neturl="https://192.168.1.5:/pmagic/pmodules"

label                   pmagic_fast_wget2
        menu label      Parted Magic Fast Test WGET2
        linux           pmagic/bzImage
        initrd          pmagic/initrd.img,pmagic/fu.img,pmagic/m.img
        append          edd=on vga=normal wget="https://192.168.1.5:/pmagic/pmodules"
```

However neither of those options work. It might be because I'm using a self made certificate on the server.

pmagic version is 2021_08_30. UEFI on test machine (ASRock Killer SLI x370) is latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with the following configuration:

- I changed `linux pmagic/bzImage.img` to `kernel pmagic/bzImage.img`
- I changed `append edd=on vga=normal netsrc=wget neturl="https://192.168.1.5:/pmagic/pmodules"` to `append edd=on vga=normal netsrc=wget neturl="https://192.168.1.5:/pmagic/pmodules" netargs="-U netboot --no-check-certificate"`

```
label                   pmagic_fast     
        menu label      Parted Magic Fast     
        kernel          pmagic/bzImage
        initrd          pmagic/initrd.img,pmagic/fu.img,pmagic/m.img
        append          edd=on vga=normal netsrc=wget neturl="https://192.168.1.5/pmagic/pmodules/" netargs="-U netboot --no-check-certificate"
```